# Django dependent/ chained drop down form

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, chained-select

I am trying to add a chained drop down form to a project I'm creating. I've tried numerous solution's including django smart select and using jQuery but I can't seem to get it to work.I want a drop down form where if one option is selected in one drop down menu more options will be displayed based on the the other drop downs.

For example if I select the state as Texas the next drop down will show cities in Texas like Dallas.

I'm using django 2.1.2 and most of the mentioned solutions are running on an older version of django.

I attatched an image to clarify. Thanks

example image:

[image]